# Why os.path.realpath doesn't work properly

Tags: python, operating-system

i just downloaded a file called "N_PR_8705_004A_.doc" in my "Downloads" folder and i want to put it into my "Stage NLP" folder using os. I know how to do it without os but i'd like that shit to work it's faster and it simply doesnt. First i tried to get the path of my file doing this:

```
import os
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("N_PR_8705_004A_.doc"))
# or os.path.realpath it's the same
```

and the result i get is:

```
'C:\\Users\\f002722\\Stage NLP'
```

whereas when i do list all the files in this folder doing:

```
os.listdir("C:\\Users\\f002722\\Stage NLP")
```

you clearly see it is simply not there:

```
['.ipynb_checkpoints',
'ADR service study - D2 (1st part).pdf',
'basetal.py',
'Codes test',
'Cours NLP.ipynb',
'e Deorbit',
'edot CDF study.pdf',
'edot_v5.pdf',
'Entrainement.ipynb',
'ESA edot workshop May 6th 2014 - Summary.msg',
'ESA_edotWorkshop-_Envisat_attitude-Copy1',
'ESA_edotWorkshop-_Envisat_attitude.pdf',
'ESA_edotWorkshop_GNC_.pdf',
'ESA_INNOCENTI_Challenges.pdf',
'ESA_Robin_Biesbroek_edot.pdf',
'GMV_edot_Symposium.pdf',
'JOP_edotWorkshop.pdf',
'KT_HAARMANN_Edot.pdf',
'MDA_edot_Symposium_-_Robotic_Capture.pdf',
'MDA_eDot_Symposium_-_Robotic_Capture.pdf.kx2zd5w.partial',
'Note_Ariane_NLP.ipynb',
'Note_Ariane_NLP_2.ipynb',
'Note_Ariane_NLP_3.ipynb',
'OHB_eDotWorkshop_ADRM.pdf',
'OHB_Sweden_eDotWorkshop_PRISMA_and_IRIDES.pdf',
'SKA_Polska_eDotWorkshop_Net_Simulator.pdf',
'TAS_Carole_Billot_edot.pdf',
'Test.ipynb',
'Text_clustering_v3_2.py',
'Webinar_OOSandADR_7May2020.pdf',
'__pycache__']
```

So what the hell is going on i'm out of ideas here.

Thx in advance

Comment: makes no sense why that happening bro

Comment: Where are you executing the script? What is your working directory?

Comment: This is may be a minimal example, but it is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't have your files or your particular directory layout, so we can't reproduce this particular behavior. If you could reproduce this behavior on a "dummy" file and directory, that would be helpful.

Comment: Dean Van Greunen: I know it drives me crazy too

Comment: ivvija: My working directory is "Stage NLP" and i'm executing this script on one of my files on this very directory

Comment: jjramsey: What do you mean bu dummy file ?

Comment: By "dummy" file, I mean a file specifically used for debugging your problem and nothing else, and can be reproduced by others so that they can see if they can reproduce your problem. It could be as simple as a text file with the contents "Testing, 1, 2, 3, ...".

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a possible answer to your question. Neither `realpath` nor `abspath` require their arguments to name existing files. In particular, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) for `abspath()` says: "On most platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function `normpath()` as follows: `normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))`."

This means that if you have a Python script that has a line like,

```py
foo = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("doesnotexist"))
```

then the value of `foo` will be the current working directory of the script. Since `"doesnotexist"` isn't the name of a file in this directory, it won't show up if you do `os.listdir(foo)`.

I notice that you wrote that "N_PR_8705_004A_.doc" was in your *"Downloads"* directory, which is obviously not the same as `'C:\\Users\\f002722\\Stage NLP'`. If `'C:\\Users\\f002722\\Stage NLP'` is the working directory for your Python script, then running `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("N_PR_8705_004A_.doc"))` is just like writing `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("doesnotexist"))`, for the reasons that I just gave.

Python can't automatically figure out the path of a file just by giving it a relative file name. For example, there could be many files named `README.txt` on a system, each in different directories, so there's no way for `os.path.abspath('README.txt')` to know *which* of those directories you want.

To move the file "N_PR_8705_004A_.doc" from the "Downloads" directory to `'C:\\Users\\f002722\\Stage NLP'`, you'd probably need to do something like this:

```py
import shutil
shutil.move('C:\\Users\\f002722\\Downloads\\N_PR_8705_004A_.doc',
            'C:\\Users\\f002722\\Stage NLP')
```

presuming, of course, that the "Downloads" directory was inside `'C:\\Users\\f002722'`.